# Shell Sort: won't work with certain combos of intervals

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, shellsort

I asked this question before, but my post was cluttered with a whole bunch of other code and wasn't clearly presented, so I'm going to try again. Sorry, I'm new here

Shell sort, how I wrote it, only works sometimes. Array `a` is an array of 100 integers unsorted, `inc` is an array of 4 integers whose values are the intervals that shell sort should use (they descend and the final value is always 1), `count` is an array which stores the counts for different runs of shell sort, `cnt` represents the count value which should be updated for this run of shell sort.

When I run shell sort multiple times, with different sets of 4 intervals, only sometimes does the sort fully work. Half the time the array is fully sorted, the other half of the time the array is partially sorted.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

```
public static void shellSort(int[] a, int[] inc, int[] count, int cnt) {
    for (int k = 0; k < inc.length; k++) {
        for (int i = inc[k], j; i < a.length; i += inc[k]) {
            int tmp = a[i];
            count[cnt] += 1;
            for (j = i - inc[k]; j >= 0; j -= inc[k]) {
                if (a[j] <= tmp)
                    break;
                a[j + inc[k]] = a[j];
                count[cnt] += 1;
            }
            a[j + inc[k]] = tmp;
            count[cnt] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code would be a lot easier to read if you fixed the indentation. Is it like that in your real source code?

Comment: Can you also provide an example of the intervals that don't work? Gotta give a us a fighting chance to help you here.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it, it seems to not work when only odd intervals are used.

Comment: @rfreak ok, nevermind, that isn't always true. Here are some examples: 9 7 5 1 - Works 7 6 3 1 - Works 8 5 4 1 - Doesn't Work 5 4 3 1 - Doesn't Work It seems to always bee the second group of numbers... am i not resetting something of importance?

Comment: you may want to see [this link](http://www.proglogic.com/code/java/sort/shellsort.php) for an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

One problem is that you're only sorting one `inc[k]`-step sequence for each `k`, while you should sort them all (you're only sorting `{a[0], a[s], a[2*s], ... , a[m*s]}`, leaving out `{a[1], a[s+1], ... , a[m*s+1]}` etc.). However, that should only influence performance (number of operations), not the outcome, since the last pass is a classical insertion sort (`inc[inc.length-1] == 1`), so that should sort the array no matter what happened before.

I don't see anything in the code that would cause failure. Maybe the `inc` array doesn't contain what it should? If you print out `inc[k]` in each iteration of the outer loop, do you get the expected output?

Comment: I kind of understand what you're saying, but am unsure of how to correct that. Is there another for loop that I'm missing?

Comment: @ReezaCoriza No, you just have to increment `i` in the middle loop by `1` instead of `inc[k]`, like Blastfurnace said. That should positively not give an out of bounds exception, if you get one, there's something else amiss.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your `i` loop control:

```
for (int i = inc[k], j; i < a.length; i += inc[k]) {
```

Should be:

```
for (int i = inc[k], j; i < a.length; i++) {
```

The inner `j` loop handles the comparison of elements that are `inc[k]` apart. The outer `i` loop should simply increment by 1, the same as the outer loop of a standard Insertion sort.

In fact, the final pass of Shellsort with an increment of 1 is identical to a standard Insertion sort.

Comment: did you mean "a.length-1"? I am getting an out of bounds exception without "-1"

Comment: Also, wouldn't this loop continue past the interval? For example, if the interval is 3, it would begin at position 3 in the array, and then increment up by one position each loop. It SHOULD stop at 5, since the interval is 3, but wouldn't this continue to the end of the array?

Comment: @ReezaCoriza: The test `i < a.length` should keep `i` within the bounds of the array. You do want `i` to continue to the end of the array. The `j` loop then works backwards towards the start of the array, comparing elements that are separated by the interval. The value of `j` begins at `i - increment` and the test `j >= 0` should keep it within the bounds of the array.

Comment: @ReezaCoriza: Compare your code for Insertion sort and Shellsort. The only difference is that where `int[k]` appears in Shellsort, the value 1 is used in Insertion sort.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, that worked. This should all become second nature eventually... right?